# 256 (8x32) LED Matrix via ESP32-Pico-Kit_V4 possible? (Daft Punk Helmet)

Tags: led, esp32

I am currently planning on a Daft Punk Helmet. But the available kits are terribly expensive.

I am looking forward to using a 8x32 LED-Matrix(with 256 separate 5mm LEDs) and having a few different display modes which include static text and also repeating animations like a wave going back and forth, or digital eyes that wink. Also a Bluetooth connection would be nice and of course portability is important.

That's why I was looking at the ESP32-Pico-Kit_V4.

My question now: Is it possible to run such a big LED-Matrix off this ESP or would I need some extra boards/controllers and if so which would be necessary.
Or is this as a whole a much bigger project than I am expecting?

PS: I don't wanna use one of the prewired 8x32 panels because they are not see-through.

-- Arduino rookie needing some help

Comment: it is just a 256 LED light string folded 7 times ... research `driving RGB LED strip with ESP32-Pico-Kit_V4`

Comment: I'll need 4 display drivers like the MAX7219 CNG chips.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: i was under the impression that you wanted color .... good luck with your project